# RPi4 : Device driver - microsecond delay/count

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, embedded, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi4

I am beginner in Linux device driver. I am trying to implement a device driver for ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04) using **Raspberry Pi 4B** with following details:

- OS : Raspberry Pi OS ( Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 buster ) ( version = 10 buster )
- Linux Version : Linux raspberrypi 5.10.20-v7l+ armv7l GNU/Linux

The problem now am facing is to create a microsecond delay for the trigger of sensor and also need to find the duration in microseconds of the ECHO signal. I tried with **usleep()** but it gives me implicit error which I couldn't solve even after trying the methods (like adding #define _BSD_SOURCE) explained in other forums. On searching it was found that **jiffies** are not able to give microsecond precision. The **clock()** function or **sched_clock()** both kept on giving errors.

It would be really helpful if any of you could suggest me a way to implement microsecond delay and count in device driver.

Thank You in advance.

**[SOLVED]**

`udelay( )` solves the issue of microsecond delay with header `linux/delay.h` .

Another issue was of finding duration of a process in microseconds, which was solved by the following codes

```
volatile unsigned int data = 0;
volatile ktime_t start;

start = ktime_get();
// process to check

data= (unsigned int) ktime_to_ns( ktime_sub( ktime_get(), start ) );
data /= 1000; // convert nanaosecond to microsecond
```

Comment: Are you writing a __kernel device driver__ / kernel module in kernel space, or are you writing an user-space application?

Comment: I am trying to create a kernel device driver for the sensor.

Comment: Linux not being a real-time OS you might get jitter and timing errors.

Comment: @Clifford I was having timing issues. So tried using kernel device driver. Is there any other RTOS which could provide micro-second precision?

Comment: @vrk2412 Not sure about RPi4 .but https://github.com/Forty-Tw0/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS.  However you'd probably loose a lot of functionality that Raspbian provides.  Using RPi4 for this is throwing a lot of inappropriate hardware and software at the problem.  It does not need a fast processor or even an RTOS, just a hardware timer with input timer capture - pretty much any cheap 8bit device has that.

Comment: @Clifford This is just a device driver which is yet to be combined with some other complex programs along with local server applications. Hence I use RPi. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion of the mentioned FreeRTOS.

Comment: I appreciate that, and that is your problem - you need other stuff to run that might rely on the functionality of Linux, making an RTOS non-viable.  If your RPi did nothing else, you might make it work, as soon as you require it to do other stuff - even moving the mouse pointer could conceivably affect result.  I am not proposing that you don't use the RPi4, merely that you offload the real-time stuff to something more suitable - connected to the RPi through I2C or SPI for example.

Comment: ... This for example: https://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=3028 if you don't want to build your own hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`udelay()` should be the function you are looking for.

`usleep()` is a function from the standard library and therefore not usable in kernel space. You will have to use linux timers. Refer to [the documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a351e9b9fc24e982ec2f0e76379a49826036da12/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt) for more information.

Comment: **This actually solved the microsecond delay issue.** But how would I find the duration of a process in microseconds? The `jiffies` does not seem to have microsecond precision.